# stuck at sprite movement

Tags: python, pygame

lately I've been working on a little project of mine.
I have a background in which I spawn alot of cars. 
I want to have those cars move along a path i define myself. I've gotten to the point where one of my cars moves to the (0,0) position when i call my move method, also, I'm not sure how to have a smooth animation along the path, I don't want the car to suddenly appear at the last waypoint define instantly.

Here is my code:

```
import assets
import pygame

##this class spawns
class bus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(bus,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((assets.bus_width,assets.bus_height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def set_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def set_image(self, filename = None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def rotate(self,angle):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(car,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((assets.car_width,assets.car_height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 2
    def set_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def get_x_position(self):
        return self.rect.x
    def get_y_position(self):
        return self.rect.y
    def set_image(self, filename = None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def rotate(self,angle):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    #not sure what to do here
    def move_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x +=
        self.rect.y +=
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class WayPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def getY(self):
        return self.y

class WayPointsList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wayPoints = []
    def add_wayPoint(self, x, y):
        self.wayPoints.append(WayPoint(x,y))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.wayPoints)
    def get_wayPoint(self, i):
        return [self.wayPoints[i].getX(), self.wayPoints[i].getY()]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    window_size = window_width, window_height = assets.screen_width, assets.screen_height
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)

    pygame.display.set_caption(assets.caption)

    window.fill(assets.white)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    car_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #mainloop
    running = True
    while running:
        #loading background
        bkg = pygame.image.load(assets.background)
        #event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    car110 = car()
                    car110.set_image(assets.furore)
                    car110.rotate(180)
                    car110.set_position(0,273)
                    car_group.add(car110)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    car109 = car()
                    car109.set_image(assets.hachura)
                    car109.rotate(180)
                    car109.set_position(0,306)
                    car_group.add(car109)
                    #i want to move this car along some waypoints I've defined in my head
                    #like so:
                    #lane = WayPointsList()
                    #lane.add_wayPoint(50, 250)
                    #lane.add_wayPoint(250, 350)
                    #after this i want to move my image along these waypoints I've defined
                elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                    car108=car()
                    car108.set_image(assets.jefferson)
                    car108.rotate(180)
                    car108.set_position(0,343)
                    car_group.add(car108)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                    car107=car()
                    car107.set_image(assets.michelli)
                    car107.rotate(270)
                    car107.set_position(410,550)
                    car_group.add(car107)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_5:
                    car106=car()
                    car106.set_image(assets.traceAM)
                    car106.rotate(270)
                    car106.set_position(460,550)
                    car_group.add(car106)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_6:
                    car105=car()
                    car105.set_image(assets.traceAM)
                    car105.set_position(750,300)
                    car_group.add(car105)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_7:
                    car104=car()
                    car104.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car104.set_position(750,265)
                    car_group.add(car104)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_8:
                    car103=car()
                    car103.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car103.rotate(90)
                    car103.set_position(294,0)
                    car_group.add(car103)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_9:
                    car102=car()
                    car102.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car102.rotate(90)
                    car102.set_position(337,0)
                    car_group.add(car102)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_0:
                    car101=car()
                    car101.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car101.rotate(90)
                    car101.set_position(380,0)
                    car_group.add(car101)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_b:
                    car201=bus()
                    car201.set_image(assets.bus)
                    car201.set_position(700,229)
                    car_group.add(car201)
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_x:
                    car_group.remove(car101,car102,car103,car104,car105,car106,car107,car108,car109,car110,car201)
        car_group.update()
        window.fill(assets.white)
        window.blit(bkg,(0,0))
        car_group.draw(window)
        clock.tick(assets.FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```

If anyone could give me some pointers or tell me what I can do to fix it, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: in class `car` you have to create method `update()` which moves car only few pixels in correct direction. `car_group.update()` will call `update()` for every car and they will moves a little in every loop.

Comment: BTW: we use `UpperCaseNames` for classes like `Surface`, `Sprite` or  `Car`, `Bus`. Even Stackoverflow knows this rule and it uses light blue color to show classes. It makes code more readable. More rules/suggestions in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: don't do `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` in `move_position` because your remove car position. `image.get_rect()` always has position `(0,0)`

Comment: Ah, so that's why my cars kept reappearing in position (0,0). As for the UpperCaseNames, I didn't know that since I'm pretty new to python and stackoverflow.

Comment: `PEP8` has only sugesstions but many peoples and tools (IDEs, pylint, pyflakes) use those suggestions to make code more readable for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `move_position` don't use

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

because `image` doesn't keep position and it has always `(x,y) == (0,0)`

In class create `update()` and run `move_position()` inside `update()` and `car_group.update()` will execute it in every loop.

I save `angle` in `self.angle` so I can use it to move in correct direction

```
radians_angle = math.radians(self.angle)

self.rect.x -= self.speed * math.cos(radians_angle)
self.rect.y -= self.speed * math.sin(radians_angle)
```

Example works without images so everyone can run it.

```
import pygame
import math

WHITE = (0,0,0)

##this class spawns
class bus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(bus,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((800, 600)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.angle = 0 # <-- default direction

    def set_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def set_image(self, filename = None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20)).convert_alpha()
            self.image.fill((255,0,0))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def rotate(self,angle):
        self.angle = angle # <-- keep it to move it in correct direction
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,angle).convert_alpha() # need alpha to correctly rotate
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(car,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 2
        self.angle = 0 # <-- default direction

    def set_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def get_x_position(self):
        return self.rect.x

    def get_y_position(self):
        return self.rect.y

    def set_image(self, filename = None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20)).convert_alpha() # need alpha to correctly rotate
            self.image.fill((0,255,0))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def rotate(self,angle):
        self.angle = angle # <-- keep it to move it in correct direction
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle).convert_alpha() # need alpha to correctly rotate
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #not sure what to do here
    def move_position(self,x,y):

        # use angle to calculate direction
        radius_angle = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.rect.x -= self.speed * math.cos(radius_angle)
        self.rect.y -= self.speed * math.sin(radius_angle)
        #print('move', self.angle, self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect() # <-- DON'T DO THIS

    def update(self):
        self.move_position(0,0)

class WayPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def getY(self):
        return self.y

class WayPointsList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wayPoints = []
    def add_wayPoint(self, x, y):
        self.wayPoints.append(WayPoint(x,y))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.wayPoints)
    def get_wayPoint(self, i):
        return [self.wayPoints[i].getX(), self.wayPoints[i].getY()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    window_size = window_width, window_height = 800, 600
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)

    window.fill(WHITE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    car_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #mainloop
    running = True
    while running:
        #loading background
        bkg = pygame.Surface((800,600)).convert()
        bkg.fill((0,0,255))                     
        #event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    car110 = car()
                    #car110.set_image(assets.furore)
                    car110.rotate(180-45) 
                    car110.set_position(0,273)
                    car_group.add(car110)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    car109 = car()
                    #car109.set_image(assets.hachura)
                    car109.rotate(180)
                    car109.set_position(0,306)
                    car_group.add(car109)
                    #i want to move this car along some waypoints I've defined in my head
                    #like so:
                    #lane = WayPointsList()
                    #lane.add_wayPoint(50, 250)
                    #lane.add_wayPoint(250, 350)
                    #after this i want to move my image along these waypoints I've defined
                elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                    car108=car()
                    #car108.set_image(assets.jefferson)
                    car108.rotate(180)
                    car108.set_position(0,343)
                    car_group.add(car108)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                    car107=car()
                    #car107.set_image(assets.michelli)
                    car107.rotate(270)
                    car107.set_position(410,550)
                    car_group.add(car107)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_5:
                    car106=car()
                    #car106.set_image(assets.traceAM)
                    car106.rotate(270)
                    car106.set_position(460,550)
                    car_group.add(car106)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_6:
                    car105=car()
                    #car105.set_image(assets.traceAM)
                    car105.set_position(750,300)
                    car_group.add(car105)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_7:
                    car104=car()
                    #car104.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car104.set_position(750,265)
                    car_group.add(car104)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_8:
                    car103=car()
                    #car103.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car103.rotate(90)
                    car103.set_position(294,0)
                    car_group.add(car103)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_9:
                    car102=car()
                    #car102.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car102.rotate(90)
                    car102.set_position(337,0)
                    car_group.add(car102)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_0:
                    car101=car()
                    #car101.set_image(assets.rumbler)
                    car101.rotate(90)
                    car101.set_position(380,0)
                    car_group.add(car101)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_b:
                    car201=bus()
                    #car201.set_image(assets.bus)
                    car201.set_position(700,229)
                    car_group.add(car201)
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_x:
                    car_group.remove(car101,car102,car103,car104,car105,car106,car107,car108,car109,car110,car201)
        car_group.update()
        window.fill(WHITE)
        window.blit(bkg,(0,0))
        car_group.draw(window)
        clock.tick(25)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This fix helped me alot! I can now move my cars. Now all i have to do is implement my waypoint classes, so that my cars move according to the waypoints. Thank you very much for the solution!